# Admob 6 on android 2.2 not working

Tags: java, android, admob

When I try to get admob 6 working on android 2.2, I see a red and black box that reads "you must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges"

How can I fix this?

Ill paste all my code below so there is no confusion.
After I couldn't get it to work in my app, I created a separate project dedicated to figuring this out.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.valgriz.AdMobTest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="MYADCODE"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java(Not Important):

```
package com.valgriz.AdMobTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a project using AdMob 6 and I have the following

```
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

I don't see the permissions either.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Also in your project.properties file try changing the target to 14

```
            target=android-14
```

Comment: Its still not working for some reason,  I still see the message.  
Is there anything else that may work?

Comment: Have you ready this? https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals#requirements  I remember having to add this after the last SDK update.  I added the external Jar from android-sdk-windows\extras\google\admob_ads_sdk\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.1.0.jar

Comment: yes, I imported the library... This is annoying me so much right now... I just want to ad adds and post my app.
thanks for your help though,

Comment: Thank you so much, I found out how to do this... I did what you said and I had to change one other thing...

Answer (score 1):

The config changes that you added:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

This code required SDK version 13 or more. So try setting the target sdk version for the app to 13 or more.